# Trying to re-loop a game only if a user says to

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to make an old rock, paper, scissors game I made better by asking the user if they would like to replay or not..

This is the code I have been working on:

```
# ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS !!!
# BY: NICK GRIMES

from random import randint

replay = True
while replay == True:
    replay = False

userChoice = raw_input("> Choose rock, paper, or scissors: ")
computerChoice = randint(1, 101)

if computerChoice <= 34:
    computerChoice = "rock"
elif computerChoice <= 67:
    computerChoice = "paper"
else:
    computerChoice = "scissors"

print "> The computer chooses: " + str(computerChoice)


if userChoice == computerChoice:
    print "> It's a tie! Thank you for playing!"
    askUserPlayAgain = raw_input("> Would you like to play again? Enter [yes or no]: ")
    if askUserPlayAgain.lower()[0] == "y":
        replay == True
    elif askUserPlayAgain.lower()[0] == "n":
        break

    # ---

elif userChoice == "rock":
    if computerChoice == "scissors":
        print "> Rock crushes scissors!"
        print "> You win!"
    else:
        print "> Paper covers rock!"
        print "> Computer wins!"

    # ---

elif userChoice == "paper":
    if computerChoice == "rock":
        print "> Paper coveres rock!"
        print "> You win!"
    else:
        print "> Scissors cuts paper!"
        print "> Computer wins!"

    # ---

elif userChoice == "scissors":
    if computerChoice == "rock":
        print "> Rock crushes scissors"
        print "> Computer wins!"
    else:
        print "> Scissors cuts paper"
        print "> You win!"

    # ---

else:
    print "Please choose either rock, paper, or scissors only!"
```

Now, the actual game has always worked, but with trying to implement this new idea, I actually deleted the function that compared the two choices, and just left them to the if/else's...

The main problem is this: when a user types 'yes', it should restart the game, but it does absolutely nothing for some reason. If anyone see's anything that could be causing this, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense to me:

```
replay = True
while replay == True:
    replay = False
```

I think you'd be better off using a `while True:` loop. Use the `continue` keyword if the user selects to restart the game and the *replay* variable is not required.

```
from random import randint

while True:
    userChoice = raw_input("> Choose rock, paper, or scissors: ")
    computerChoice = randint(1, 101)
    if computerChoice <= 34:
        computerChoice = "rock"
    elif computerChoice <= 67:
        computerChoice = "paper"
    else:
        computerChoice = "scissors"
    print("> The computer chooses: " + str(computerChoice))
    if userChoice == computerChoice:
        print("> It's a tie! Thank you for playing!")
    askUserPlayAgain = raw_input("> Would you like to play again? Enter [yes or no]: ")
    if askUserPlayAgain.lower()[0] == "y":
        continue
    elif askUserPlayAgain.lower()[0] == "n":
        break
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but it told me I'm not allowed to until I have 15 reputation :/

Comment: @FourTwenty you should be able to click the 'tick' symbol next to the best/most helpful answer just now and then the upvote or downvote icons when you have 15 reputation

Comment: I just clicked the check mark, that may or may not be what you were referring to haha.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed

```
while replay == True:
```

to

```
while  True:
```

and it just work fine for me.